# Related rates problem question

Tags: calculus

A spherical ballon is expanding in such a way that its volume is increasing at 6 cubic centimetres per second. Find the rate of increase of the surface of the ballon when its volume is $ 36 \pi \;cm^3$.

I don't understand the last step in the answer.

Answer:

We are given that $ \frac{dV}{dt} = 6$

and we are ask to find $\frac{dA}{dt}$ when the volume is $ V = \frac{4}{3} \pi\ r^3 = 36\pi$

Solving this equation we find the radius of the ballon $ r=3 $

In order to find the rate of increase of the surface area we apply the chain rule:

$$ \frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{dA}{dr}\cdot\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{\frac{dA}{dr}\cdot\frac{dV}{dt}}{\frac{dV}{dr}}=\frac{8\pi r\cdot6}{4\pi r^2}=\frac{12}{r}=\frac{12}{3}=4 $$

I don't get what he did in the last step. (I know that he applied the chain rule.)

Why didn't he do this instead: $\frac{dA}{dt} A = 8\pi r \cdot \frac{dr}{dt} $ and solve for A?

Comment: Your long equation near the end of the post is not correct. You must have meant$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{dA}{dr}\cdot\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{\frac{dA}{dr}\cdot\frac{dV}{dt}}{\frac{dV}{dr}}=\frac{8\pi r\cdot6}{4\pi r^2}=\frac{12}{r}=\frac{12}{3}=4
$. That being said, your final equation is also wrong. IT should be $\frac{dA}{dt}= 8\pi r \cdot \frac{dr}{dt}$. In which case you will see that the two equations are equal because $\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{\frac{dV}{dt}}{\frac{dV}{dr}}$.

Comment: Yes i agree with @Geoffrey since $A$ depends on $r$ and $r$ depends on $t$ we have by the chain rule that $\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{dA}{dr}\cdot\frac{dr}{dt}$.

Answer (score 1):

First, the volume is $V={4\over 3}\pi r^3$ and the surface area is $S=4\pi r^2$.

You are given ${dV\over dt}=6$ and you want to find ${dS\over dt}{\Large|}_{V=36\pi}$. (I presume this is the case since you didn't say with respect to what variable that you wanted to find the rate of change of $S$. Usually in these problems it is the rate of change with respect to *time*, so I will proceed.) But $V=36\pi\implies r=3$, so you want to find ${dS\over dt}\Large|_{r=3}$.

Now, $${dS\over dt}{\Huge|}_{r=3}=\left[8\pi r{dr\over dt}\right]_{r=3},$$ so we need to determine ${dr\over dt}{\Large|}_{r=3}$. However,
$${dV\over dt}{\Huge|}_{r=3}=\left[4\pi r^2{dr\over dt}\right]_{r=3}=36\pi {dr\over dt}{\Huge|}_{r=3}=6 \implies {dr\over dt}{\Huge|}_{r=3}={1\over 6\pi}.$$
Thus, $${dS\over dt}{\Huge|}_{r=3}=\left[8\pi r{dr\over dt}\right]_{r=3}=8\pi(3)\left({1\over 6\pi}\right)=4.$$